# How to statistic order (sum total by date, count quantity by products) in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, statistics, aggregate, aggregation

I have order data model below. I want to query to statistic order: sum total by date and count quantity by products in mongoDB.  ..........................................................................
(Below eg is details about the questions)
My order data:

```
    [
  {
    "status": "Not processed",
    "total": 97000,
    "_id": "62ef7da24b535854c85a4bfc",
    "cart": {
      "_id": "62ef7da24b535854c85a4bfa",
      "user": "6280676782dc052a6c5cb91e",
      "products": [
        {
          "purchasePrice": 97000,
          "totalPrice": 97000,
          "_id": "62ef7da24b535854c85a4bfb",
          "quantity": 1,
          "product": {
            "_id": "62ab02ebd3e608133c947793",
          }
        }
      ],
    },
    "createdAt": "2022-09-30T12:08:56.161Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-10-01T15:48:08.868Z"
  },
  {
    "status": "Shipped",
    "total": 489500,
    "_id": "62f27087e32f0e4364d71170",
    "cart": {
      "_id": "62f27087e32f0e4364d7116e",
      "user": "6280676782dc052a6c5cb91e",
      "products": [
        {
          "purchasePrice": 97900,
          "totalPrice": 489500,
          "_id": "62f27087e32f0e4364d7116f",
          "quantity": 5,
          "product": {
            "_id": "62ab02ebd3e608133c947793",
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "createdAt": "2022-10-01T11:08:17.731Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-10-02T08:24:21.091Z"
  },
  {
    "status": "Processing",
    "total": 238000,
    "_id": "63005a7c9587382c2c20201d",
    "cart": {
      "_id": "63005a7c9587382c2c20201b",
      "user": "6280676782dc052a6c5cb91e",
      "products": [
        {
          "purchasePrice": 47600,
          "totalPrice": 238000,
          "quantity": 5,
          "product": {
            "_id": "62ab02ebd3e608133c947795",
          }
        }
      ],
      "created": "2022-08-20T03:52:28.180Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "createdAt": "2022-10-01T11:08:44.717Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-10-01T11:08:44.717Z"
  }
]
```

My query MongoDb:

```
let endDate = new Date("2022-10-04T00:08:17.731Z");
let startDate = new Date("2022-09-25T00:08:56.161");
        const order = await Order
            .aggregate([
                { $match: { "createdAt": { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate } } },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        createdAt: {
                            $dateFromParts: {
                                year: {
                                    $year: "$createdAt"
                                }, month: {
                                    $month: "$createdAt"
                                }, day: {
                                    $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        dateRange: { $map: { input: { $range: [0, { $subtract: [endDate, startDate] }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24] }, in: { $add: [startDate, "$$this"] } } }
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$dateRange" },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: {
                            date: "$dateRange",
                        },
                        count: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$dateRange", "$createdAt"] }, 1, 0] } },
                        subtotal: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$dateRange", "$createdAt"] }, "$total", 0] } },
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$_id.date",
                        totalPrice: { $sum: "$count" },
                        subtotal: { $sum: "$subtotal" },
                    }
                },
                { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        date: "$_id",
                        totalPrice: "$totalPrice",
                        subtotal: "$subtotal",
                    }
                }
])
```

But actualy result is:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2022-09-24T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-26T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-27T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-28T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-29T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-30T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-10-01T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-10-02T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-10-03T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  }
]
```

My expected result is:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2022-09-24T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-25T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-26T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-27T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-28T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-29T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-09-30T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 97000,
    "subtotal": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-10-01T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 727500,
    "subtotal": 2
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-10-02T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-10-03T17:08:56.161Z",
    "totalPrice": 0,
    "subtotal": 0
  }
]
```

And I want to statistic order with count quantity by products, how can I do this?

Comment: Which MongoDB Version do you use?

Comment: I use mongodb version 5.0.13

Comment: Consider upgrade to 6.0. It provides `$densify` and `$fill` which would be very helpful (see answer below). With version 5, the query significantly becomes more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution does not work because you compare exact values of createdAt and dates generated by range. I used easier approach using $bucket aggregation.

Please make sure to add "Z" in startDate variable creation string to avoid unexpected results caused by timezones.

Here is the solution that works for me for given example documents:

```
// select database
use("data")

// dates that we care
let endDate = new Date("2022-10-04T00:08:17.731Z");
let startDate = new Date("2022-09-25T00:08:56.161Z");

// generate boundaries
let boundaries = [startDate]
while (boundaries.slice(-1)[0] <= endDate){
  boundaries.push(
    new Date(new Date(boundaries.slice(-1)[0]).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
  )
}

// create aggregation query
p = [
  { $match: { "createdAt": { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate } } },
  {
    $bucket: {
      boundaries: boundaries,
      groupBy: "$createdAt",
      default: "other",
      output: {
        subtotal: {$sum: 1},
        totalPrice: {$sum: "$total"},
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $densify: {
      field: "_id",
      range:{
        step: 1,
        unit: "day",
        bounds: [startDate, endDate],
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      totalPrice: {$ifNull: ["$totalPrice", 0]},
      subtotal: {$ifNull: ["$subtotal", 0]},
      date: { $dateToString: { date: "$_id" } },
      _id: 0,
    }
  },
]
// run
db.your_collection.aggregate(p)
```

And the result:

```
[
    {
        "totalPrice": 0,
        "subtotal": 0,
        "date": "2022-09-25T00:08:56.161Z"
    },
    {
        "totalPrice": 0,
        "subtotal": 0,
        "date": "2022-09-26T00:08:56.161Z"
    },
    {
        "totalPrice": 0,
        "subtotal": 0,
        "date": "2022-09-27T00:08:56.161Z"
    },
    {
        "totalPrice": 0,
        "subtotal": 0,
        "date": "2022-09-28T00:08:56.161Z"
    },
    {
        "totalPrice": 0,
        "subtotal": 0,
        "date": "2022-09-29T00:08:56.161Z"
    },
    {
        "totalPrice": 97000,
        "subtotal": 1,
        "date": "2022-09-30T00:08:56.161Z"
    },
    {
        "totalPrice": 727500,
        "subtotal": 2,
        "date": "2022-10-01T00:08:56.161Z"
    },
    {
        "totalPrice": 0,
        "subtotal": 0,
        "date": "2022-10-02T00:08:56.161Z"
    },
    {
        "totalPrice": 0,
        "subtotal": 0,
        "date": "2022-10-03T00:08:56.161Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Instead of `totalPrice: {$ifNull: ["$totalPrice", 0]}` you can also use new [$fill](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/fill/)

Comment: I use mongoDb version 5.0.13 so I have error when run query: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$densify'. Do you have other solution?

Comment: You can remove $densify stage at all and in the results fill in missing days after aggregation by some backend/frontend code, as without $densify days with 0 values will not be present in results.